# -bash: monkeyrunner: command not found

Tags: android-studio, testing, terminal, monkeyrunner

I am trying to see how `monkeyrunner`works. I have python script that I want to test it on my android virtual device. I tried running below command through terminal:

`monkeyrunner script.py`

I am at: `/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/monkeyrunner`, python file is also in the same directory.

but it returns that: `-bash: monkeyrunner: command not found`

So I tried another way, and I opened monkeyrunner exec file, then tried to run script.py through it, but still giving this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'script' is not defined
```

I also tried `monkeyrunner script.py` inside monkeyrunner exec file but gives this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    monkeyrunner script.py
                ^
SyntaxError: mismatched input 'script' expecting NEWLINE
```

Can anyone help, how to run a python script using androidstudio's monkeyrunner in MacOS and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am new to macOS I wasn't sure that terminal kind of work the same as cmd on Windows, but after trying `./monkeyrunner script.py`, finally my python script successfully run on monkeyrunner.

Also I noticed another point that if someone else get stuck into this issue and doesn't like to put `./` every time he/she executes a command, he/she can just put the monkeyrunner path in his/her environment path variables.

For macOS the paths file is here:
/etc/paths

Comment: hey what is the exact path to be added there?